# MediaPlayer Error unknown err

Tags: android, cordova

I am using ionic 2.

I refered this https://github.com/nchutchind/cordova-plugin-streaming-media

Here is my code

```
  constructor(private streamingMedia: StreamingMedia,public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {

    var videoUrl = "http://came3.nkansai.ne.jp:81/nphMotionJpeg?Resolution=640x480&Quality=Motion";

    let options: StreamingVideoOptions = {
      successCallback: () => { console.log('Video played') },
      errorCallback: (e) => { 
      console.log('Error streaming')
      console.log(e) 
     },
      orientation: 'landscape'
    };



    this.streamingMedia.playVideo('http://came3.nkansai.ne.jp:81/nphMotionJpeg?Resolution=640x480&Quality=Motion', options);
 }
```

I am getting this err

MediaPlayer Error: Unknown (1) -2147483648

Kindly advice me,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the above mentioned scenario, follow the below mentioned steps:
-> add the below code in config.xml:

```
    <allow-intent href="*" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="data:*" />
```

-> add the below code in index.html:

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; connect-src *">
```

Comment: Does it have to be built and install on the device or can you simply test this with "ionic cordova run --device android" ?